# Time and space complexity of Number of Dice Rolls With Target Sum

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm solving [Number of dice rolls with target sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-dice-rolls-with-target-sum/).

> You have n dice, and each die has k faces numbered from 1 to k.

> Given three integers n, k, and target, return the number of possible ways (out of the k^n total ways) to roll the dice, so the sum of the face-up numbers equals target. Since the answer may be too large, return it modulo 10^9 + 7.

I have the recursive solution below (not working on optimizing it just yet).

```py
def numRollsToTarget(self, n: int, k: int, target: int) -> int:
        modulo = 10**9 + 7
        def permutations(dice, k, target):
            if dice == 0:
                return 1 if target == 0 else 0
            num_ways = 0
            for i in range(1, k+1):
                num_ways += permutations(dice-1, k, target-i)
            return num_ways
                
        return permutations(n, k, target) % modulo
```

Given `k` = number of faces on die, `n` = number of dice, `t` = target
When I draw out the recursive tree, it seems like the time complexity should be `O(k^n)` and the space complexity is `O(n)`. Should I be including `t` in the analysis anywhere? I've taken a peek at some of the memoization solutions and they have `O(n*t*k)` as the time complexity and `O(n*t)` as the space complexity.

Comment: Seems correct to me

Comment: The solution checks all `k^n` possible rolls, regardless of `t`, so yes, the time complexity is `O(k^n)`. To create a dependency on `t`, you could add a base case like `if target < 0: return 0`. The memoization solutions are doing something equivalent to that, and more.

Comment: As a side note, you are counting [restricted compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of the target number.  [This paper](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-5/abramson.pdf) gives a formula for the number of these compositions (p. 441, formula E). In the notation of this formula n is the target number, k is the number of dice, and w is the biggest number on a die.

Comment: Seems the memoization solutions like the DP solutions are reducing complexity down to O(n*t*k).  See [Leet Code 1155. Number of Dice Rolls With Target Sum — Graphical Explained Python3 Solution](https://medium.com/tech-life-fun/leet-code-1155-number-of-dice-rolls-with-target-sum-graphical-explained-python3-solution-224f8c0af23)